# Change button state according to checkbox selection in recycler view in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I am having one recycler view with an adapter class. In the single item view there is a checkbox also. In my layout view it contains one button and recycler view mentioned above. When i checks on any check box in the view the button should get activated (Changing the color to active). When nothing is selected on the view button should become in the form of deactivated. How can i possible? Any example? Code is below

```
public class PlatformAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlatformAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Batch> batches;
ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses;
boolean isInstituteStudent;

public void setBatches(ArrayList<Batch> batches) {
    this.batches = batches;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setCourses(ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ArrayList<CourseSlug> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public ArrayList<Batch> getBatches() {
    return batches;
}

public void setInstituteStudent(boolean instituteStudent) {
    isInstituteStudent = instituteStudent;
}

public boolean isInstituteStudent() {
    return isInstituteStudent;
}

public PlatformAdapter() {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
    batches = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell_platform_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (isInstituteStudent) {
        Batch batch = batches.get(position);
        holder.enrolment.setText(batch.getName());
        holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(batch.isPreselect());
    } else {
        final CourseSlug course = courses.get(position);
        holder.enrolment.setText(course.getName());
        holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(course.isPreselect());


    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return isInstituteStudent ? batches.size() : courses.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView enrolment;
    CheckBox selectEnrollment;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        enrolment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                int index = getLayoutPosition();
                if(isInstituteStudent) {
                    Batch batch = batches.get(index);
                    batch.setPreselect(b);
                } else {
                    CourseSlug course = courses.get(index);
                    course.setPreselect(b);



                        }
                    }


        });

    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}
}
```

My Recyclerview and button implemented class is given below

```
public class SelectPlatform extends BaseActivity {

PlatformAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_platform);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    initializeViews(
            findViewById(R.id.ll_content_area),
            findViewById(R.id.tv_error),
            findViewById(R.id.pb_loading)
    );

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_platform);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new PlatformAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


private void renderCourses(ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Select Courses");
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_select_enrollment);
    title.setText("Select your courses");
    adapter.setInstituteStudent(false);
    adapter.setCourses(courses);
}

private void renderInstitute(Institute institute) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Select Batches");
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_select_enrollment);
    title.setText("Select your batches at " + institute.getName());
    adapter.setInstituteStudent(true);
    adapter.setBatches(institute.getBatches());

    // Save institute name
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putString("institute_name", institute.getName());
    editor.commit();
}

public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    findViewById(R.id.pb_loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.tv_error).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.ll_content_area).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(adapter.isInstituteStudent()) {
        ArrayList<Batch> batches = adapter.getBatches();

        ArrayList<Integer> batchIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Batch batch: batches) {
            if(batch.isPreselect())
                batchIds.add(batch.getId());
        }
        GeneralApiService.addBatches(this, batchIds);
    } else {
        ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses = adapter.getCourses();
        ArrayList<String> courseSlgus = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CourseSlug course: courses) {
            if(course.isPreselect())
                courseSlgus.add(course.getSlug());
        }
        GeneralApiService.addCourses(this, courseSlgus);
    }
    new SavePlatformNamesTask().execute();
}
```

Comment: Button is in your RecycleviewAdapter or is it separate to Recycleview?

Comment: @MavyaSoni no its a seperate view

Answer (score 0):

Send your Button reference in adapter class like this.
public void setBatches(ArrayList batches,Button button) and do anything as you want.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Your button in your main class and checkbox is inside your adpter class right.

Comment: Please share your code where you call your adapter function to load recyclerview.

Comment: it is just viewing of recycler view using layout. And one button outside the recycler view container. This button should be controlled.

Comment: Just pass your button with your ArrayList inside adapter class.

Comment: you can do alse .public PlatformAdapter(Button button) {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
    batches = new ArrayList<>();
}

Answer (score 0):

**Make** a field variable in your `SelectPlatform` and set it to `0`

```
private int checkedBoxs = 0;
```

**And** also make a public method in your `SelectPlatform` like that:

```
public void updateButtonState(int num){
   checkedBoxs+=num;
   if(checkedBoxs > 0){
     //Activate the BTN
   }else{
     //Deactivate the BTN
   }
}
```

**And** Modify you Adapter's call to include a reference from your `SelectPlatform`

```
adapter = new PlatformAdapter(SelectPlatform.this);
```

**Also** don't forget to modify the Adapter to receive that reference as follows:

a) add a field variable to the adapter:

```
private SelectPlatform mThis;
```

b) modify the constructor:

```
public PlatformAdapter(SelectPlatform activity) {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
    batches = new ArrayList<>();
    mThis = activity;
}
```

**Finally** in you adapter add/modify `onCheckedChanged` of the `checkbox` and call `updateButtonState` as follows:

```
selectEnrollment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(selectEnrollment.isChecked()) {
                  mThis.updateState(1);
                } else {
                  mThis.updateState(-1);
                }
        });
```

Note: It is not necessary for the method to be public but it must have an access modifier that allows the adapter to access it.

Comment: updateState is not possible to use in adapter class.It is not visible there

Comment: Show me How do u call it? U need to use your context reference !

Comment: How to call it using context reference?

Comment: @Arjun can you please show me how you are setting the adapter so I can help you

Comment: @Arjun check the answer again now, I have modified it

Answer (score 0):

You can set an interface inside your adapter and than implement that interface in your activity containing button to be activated and then on click event of checkbox send a callback in activity and do whatever changes you want.

Example:

MyAdapter.java

```
private MyInterface mListener;

public MyAdpater(Context context, MyInterface listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

selectEnrollment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                // make a callback
                mListener.onCheckBoxClick(true);

                int index = getLayoutPosition();
                if(isInstituteStudent) {
                    Batch batch = batches.get(index);
                    batch.setPreselect(b);
                } else {
                    CourseSlug course = courses.get(index);
                    course.setPreselect(b);

                        }
                    }


        });

public interface MyInterface {
    void onCheckBoxClick(boolean isAnyChecked); 
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapter.MyInterface {
    // other stuff....


    // Pass listener instance when initializing adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, this);


    @Override
    public void onCheckBoxClick(boolean isAnyChecked) {
        if(isAnyChecked) {
            // Activate button      
        } else {
            // Deactivate button
        }
    }
}
```